# Accessing Infinispan cache container fails

Tags: caching, jboss, lookup, infinispan

In my process to migrate a working EAR application to JBoss AS 7.1.1-Finel I faced another problem what I can not solve. Shortly, an EJB3 looks up for a cache container and stores data in it.

```
org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer container = null;
...
public static CacheContainer getCacheContainer() {
    if(container == null) {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            container = (CacheContainer) ctx
                    .lookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/mycache");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
    return container;
}
```

The EAR defines the dependency on infinispan in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml, in this way:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When I deploy this code I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/infinispan/manager/CacheContainer
```

Could somebody help me?

Best regards,
SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work for a top-level deployment, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile). You may need to move the `org.infinispan` dependency to the relevant `sub-deployment` section:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  ...
  <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the war's module, for an ear -->
  <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder     -->
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      ...
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
    <!-- This corresponds to the module for a web deployment -->
    <!-- it can use all the same tags as the <deployment> entry above -->
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main" />
    </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>
  ...
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. However, shouldn't that work as a global dependency as well, e.g. like we do with e.g. org.hibernate.commons-annotations etc.? The doc you linked says the deployment dependencies are global ones just as if they were added to the manifest (which is what the Infinispan doc suggests). Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you're referring to the _Global Modules_ section, than yes - it should work on that level as well. Keep in mind though, that this is unrelated to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, since the `<global-modules>` section is put in application server config (e.g. `standalone.xml`), not in the deployment descriptor itself.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński hmm, I think we have a misunderstanding here. What I meant is a deployment global dependency, i.e. one defined under `<deployment>`. From my (admittedly incomplete) tests, it looks like I need to define the dependency for the entire deployment as well as the subdeployment, but that is probably because I have infinispan-cdi.jar in my global (read ear's) lib folder.